# Not able to centre elements in UIstackview?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistackview, ios14

I was working on a live playground project and I created everything programmatically but I am not able to align my buttons in the stackView to centre please help me
here is code for the main playground

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit
let vc = HomeViewController()
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
navController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 600)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = navController
```

here is my code for HomeVC

```
import UIKit

public class HomeViewController:UIViewController{
    let stackView:UIStackView = {
       let st = UIStackView()
        st.axis = .horizontal
        st.alignment = .center
        st.distribution = .fillEqually
        st.backgroundColor = .cyan
        st.spacing = 10
        st.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
       return st
    }()
    let generateButton:UIButton = {
       let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("Generate Array", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = .yellow

        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()
    let generateButton2:UIButton = {
       let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("Generate 2", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = .brown

        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()
    
    public override   func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(generateButton)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(generateButton2)

        
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
    }
}
```

[image: here is the output picture]
All I want is to align the buttons in that stack view to centre ..... please help me

Comment: I see they're centered ?

Comment: *"... align my buttons in the stackView to centre ..."* - it's not at all clear what you mean by that. Do you want them centered **Horizontally**? Or centered **Vertically** in the whole view? Or do you want the yellow button centered **above** the brown button? It would be easier to help you if you show an image of what you **want** as a result.

Comment: the stackView is the one with .cyan background color , I want that buttons entered vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buttons are centred correctly, `UINavigationBar` give you an illusion that they are not. To fix the issue, you have few options:

---

Hide navigation bar:

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

---

Remove navigation bar translucency:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

---

Set `edgesForExtendedLayout` to an empty array ([Source](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-stop-your-view-going-under-the-navigation-bar-using-edgesforextendedlayout)):

```
edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```

---

All these actions can be performed in `viewDidLoad()` function.

Comment: I actually used `navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)` but it made my nav bar disappear I want my NavBar visible I also tried to set navBar's background color but no effect `navController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .red`

Comment: @YuvrajAgarkar Yes, it does, thats why I provided more alternative options.

Comment: hey , yes the second one worked thank you it , I have to take a look about the translucency I Never knew something like this exist

Comment: hey @Tomas Jablonskis , can you tell me in short what happened like what was wrong and how the second solution worked for me ? Was my home vc hiding behind the navController?

Comment: @YuvrajAgarkar Yes, your `UIViewController` view was hiding behind navigation bar, because it was transparent. You can read more [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-stop-your-view-going-under-the-navigation-bar-using-edgesforextendedlayout).

Comment: hey @Tomas Jablonskis, I used this `navController.edgesForExtendedLayout = []` but its showing the same effect as the image above the second solutions seems to work though , and one more question does this happens only while using programmatic UI or happens with the storyboard too like the hiding process?

Comment: @YuvrajAgarkar Set `edgesForExtendedLayout = []` in your `viewDidLoad`